# Rails Mailer error: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Hello im reading Agile Web Development With Rails 4th Edition Book but im getting an error at 'Task H: Sending Mail'

I have mailer **order_notifier.rb**

```
class OrderNotifier < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "name@email.tld"

  def received
    @order = order
    mail(:to => order.email, :subject => 'Pragmatic Store Order Confirmation')
  end

  def shipped
    @order = order
    mail(:to => order.email, :subject => 'Pragmatic Store Order Shipped')
  end
end
```

i have **templates** /views/order_notifier/ **received**.text.erb and **shipped**.text.erb like

```
Dear <%= @order.name %>
Thank you for your recent order from The Pragmatic Store.
You ordered the following items:
<%= render @order.line_items %>
We'll send you a separate e-mail when your order ships.
```

i run it from **OrdersController**
im not sure if use current_cart or @cart but i guess it doesnt matter

```
def create
    @order = Order.new(params[:order])
    @order.add_line_items_from_cart(current_cart)
    #@order.add_line_items_from_cart(@cart)

    respond_to do |format|
 if @order.save
    Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
    session[:cart_id] = nil
    OrderNotifier.received(@order).deliver
```

the **error** im getting tels me that received method has one argument more than it needs (@order) but thats how its written in the book.. error:

```
ArgumentError in OrdersController#create
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

Where is the mistake ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is that your `received` method in the OrderNotifier does not take an argument, but your controller is passing it one. You should modify the notifier to take one argument, `order`.

On a side note, I do not recommend reading Agile Web Development With Rails.

Comment: Thank you, it works.. anyway why you dont recommend reading that book it helped me a lot

Comment: okay, its true that sometime i need to look on actualized information on book website because of different rails version. thanks

Comment: I think Agile Web Development With Rails is a great starter book for someone looking to build apps in Rails; I haven't seen 'numerous' errors in the book...